# Force Close whenever open application?

Tags: android, forceclose

Application going background from last 2-3 hours and whenever open an application from background.
It shows `NullPointerException` Error.

In My application I used some class variable are used to store data.after 2-3 hours application didn't get any data.That's why it show force close error.

Can anybody tell ,how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Post the logcat here

Comment: Post Your LogCat, and also what kind of data you have.

Comment: I used static variables and object level variables and most of data fetched from offline store?

Comment: This caused my application to crash after going to the home screen and reentering my application.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Exception handling mechanism. Like this. Put your vulnerable code in try block, if it won't get any data than `NullPointerException` will be catched by `catch block` and you can inform the user what is going wrong.

```
try
{
   //yourcode
}catch(NullPointerException e1)
{
   //Catch block
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the time app runs in background, as far as I know , the system can free the memory (including your variables) if needed.
You can verify if a variable is null and if so, give value again.

Something like this, before you use the variable's content:

```
if (config == null)
  loadConfig();
```